# Incompatible pointer type with NSDate

Tags: cocoa, pointers, nsdate

I can't see why this doesn't work. The following code block throws a warning at the addObject line: "Passing argument 1 of 'taskWithText:dueDate:' from incompatible pointer type"

```
    - (id)init{
            self = [super init];
            if (self) {
                taskListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                [taskListArray addObject:[AFLTask taskWithText:"@Helloski" dueDate:[NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"12/31/12"]]];
            }
            return self;
        }
```

It's so simple I don't see why it doesn't work. It seems to match my method:

```
- (id)initWithText:(NSString *)newText dueDate:(NSDate *)newDueDate{
    if(self = [super init]){
        taskText = [newText retain];
        taskDue = [newDueDate retain];
        taskCompleted = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (id)taskWithText:(NSString *)newText dueDate:(NSDate *)newDueDate{
    return [[[AFLTask alloc] initWithText:newText dueDate:newDueDate] autorelease];
}
```

What is going on here? I'm pretty new to Objective-C (but not programming in general) and so I'm still trying to wrap my head around pointers -- but shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself:

```
"@Helloski"
```

should be

```
@"Helloski"
```